# how do I search a table in a database where I am not certain of what column to find the data

Tags: sql-server

I am building an automation solution and I have this scenario. I have a table which contains a lot of records, the table has specific columns firstname ,lastname ,middle name & many other columns. Now I have a data that is "SICHLER ROBERT NATHAN" but i am not sure which of the names is first,last or middle name but  I want to search the table on the database until and find something that has "SICHLER ROBERT NATHAN". it doesn't matter which ever other it comes as. the database is Microsoft sql
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ufskC.png)

I was ding something like this but its getting so messy and throwing compile errors
`Select * From (Select *  From VotersLeads Where lastname Like '%sichler%' Or firstname Like '%sichler%' Or middlename Like '%sichler%') Where lastname Like '%robert%' Or firstname Like '%robert%' Or middlename Like '%robert%'`

Comment: Don’t reinvent wheels like this from scratch - so many solutions out there! https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/7253/sql-search-column-string-table-view/

Comment: Create a computed (persisted) column like this: `ALTER TABLE VotersLeads ADD FullName AS  CONCAT(FirstName, ' ', MiddleName, ' ', LastName) PERSISTED` and then search using it. Optionally you can create an index over the computed column.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your are searching through just `FirstName`, `MiddleName` and `LastName` columns, a combination of these six states would do the job:

```
Select *  From VotersLeads Where 
(firstname Like '%SICHLER%' AND middlename Like '%ROBERT%' AND lastname  Like '%NATHAN%') OR
(firstname Like '%SICHLER%' AND lastname Like '%ROBERT%' AND middlename Like '%NATHAN%') OR
(middlename Like '%SICHLER%' AND firstname Like '%ROBERT%' AND lastname Like '%NATHAN%') OR
(middlename Like '%SICHLER%' AND lastname Like '%ROBERT%' AND firstname Like '%NATHAN%') OR
(lastname Like '%SICHLER%' AND firstname Like '%ROBERT%' AND middlename Like '%NATHAN%') OR
(lastname Like '%SICHLER%' AND middlename Like '%ROBERT%' AND firstname Like '%NATHAN%')
```